# JSP User Hit Counter

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to count how many times each user enters the website, but my problem is that even though I change the user name, the hit count doesn't restart. Also, once I reload the webpage, the the name of the user becomes "null".

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="SaveName.jsp">
Who are You ? <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=username SIZE=20>
<P><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>

<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Applcation object in JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
 <%
   String name = request.getParameter( "username" );
    session.setAttribute( "theName", name );
   Integer hitsCount = 
     (Integer)application.getAttribute("hitCounter");
   if( hitsCount ==null || hitsCount == 0){
   /* First visit */
   out.println("Welcome to my website! ");

   hitsCount = 1;
}else{
   /* return visit */
   out.println("Welcome back to my website!");
   hitsCount += 1;
}
application.setAttribute("hitCounter", hitsCount);
%>
 <%= session.getAttribute( "theName" ) %>
<br>Total number of visits: <%= hitsCount%></br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is some confusion what you want to do ? Do you want hit count for each user ?

Comment: yes i want hit count for each user

Answer (score 1):

In Your JSP

```
<%!
Map<String,Integer> userCountMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
Integer hitsCount=0;
String key;
%>


<%
    String name = request.getParameter( "username" );
    if(name!=null && !"".equals(name)){
        key=name.toLowerCase();
        if(userCountMap.get(key)!=null){
            /* return visit */
            out.println("<h3>"+name+"</h3>&nbsp;Welcome back to my website!");
            hitsCount = userCountMap.get(key);
            hitsCount+=1;

        }else{
            out.println("<h3>"+name+"</h3>&nbsp;Welcome to my website!");
            hitsCount=1;
        }
        userCountMap.put(key, hitsCount);
    }
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the hit counts per user or you are storing just the hit counts?

In the former case, you can use a map that will check whether there is an entry for a specific user in the map. If entry is found, increase the counter by 1, if entry is not found, then create a new entry and set corresponding counter to 1.

In the later case, all you need to do is increase the counter every time the website is hit.